# Fonts are not displaying in Firefox

Tags: firefox, fonts, font-face

My fonts are working in all browsers except Firefox. I acquired these fonts by downloading them from Google Fonts. Then I ran them through the Fontsquirrel font generator so that I could use them in an @fontface declaration. My firefox console reports this CSS error for each font file format:

downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "graduateregular" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147500037 source: file:///C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/Web%20Projects/Uncsstalumni.com/CSS/graduate-regular-webfont.woff

My HTML:

```
<link href='../CSS/stylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

My CSS:

```
@font-face {
    font-family:'graduateregular';
    src: url('graduate-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), url('graduate-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('graduate-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('graduate-regular-webfont.svg#graduateregular') format('svg');
    src: url('graduate-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('graduate-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: Is this website live, or are you only running it on your local machine?

Comment: I'm only running it on my local machine

Comment: Will you try putting it on https://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/70d26Lc9/